# Advanced where Laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently stuck on a single `where` Laravel query. The problem is, I want to filter some data depending on latest record from a given table. Currently, my query looks like this:

```
$clients = $clients->whereDoesntHave('bill')->orWhereHas('bill', function ($query) use ($activeSchoolYear){
     $query
         ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::parse($activeSchoolYear->start));
 })
```

Where `$activeSchoolYear->start` is today's date.

The problem occurs if there are multiple records in my bills table. So for an example, if I have two records with separate dates:

```
ID | Name  | created_at          |
1  | test  | 2019-09-09 15:31:25|
2  | test2 | 2018-09-10 16:42:44|
```

The query still return both dates, even if one of them is false. I think that query looks for all the records in database, and still returns the given user, because one of the dates is correct. My question is, is it possible to target only the latest row from database. Or this can't be done using eloquent. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

As @Caddy suggested, I used a query scope, but I modified it a bit:

```
public function scopeNoActiveBill($query){
  return $query
            ->groupBy('created_at')->take(1)
            ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::create(2019, 9, 1));
}
```

I tried to take only the last row from the bills table. Then, inside controller, this is my query:

```
$clients = $clients->whereDoesntHave('bill')
     ->orWhereHas('bill', function ($query) use ($activeSchoolYear){
            $query->noActiveBill();
      })
      ->whereHas('contracts', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query
                  ->where('contract_type', '<', 2)
                  ->where('signed', 1)
                  ->where('school_year_id', $request['school_year']);
       });
```

So, I want both clients without any bills, or clients with bills that fit the given criteria. The query works fine if client has only one bill, but the problem is when client has more than one bill. If any of those bills fits the given scope, it returns the bill. I want to only check the latest record, and return the bill if that records fits the scope criteria.

EDIT 2:

Thanks to `@Caddy DZ`'s asnwer, I managed to get desired result. I just changed condition to watch for clients that don't have bills created past given date. Query scope:

```
public function scopeNoActiveBill($query){
     return $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::create(2019, 9, 1));
}
```

Controller:

```
$clients = $clients->whereDoesntHave('bill')
    ->orWhereDoesntHave('bill', function ($query) use ($activeSchoolYear){
        $query->noActiveBill();
    });
```

Comment: Currently you are only filtering `clients` and not `bills`, why do you expect to only get one bill? Where are you getting multiple bills? when you call `$client->bills`? You could use `$client->bills()->latest()->first();` to get the latest bill of the client.

Comment: I tried to get bills with relation from user. I can't just use `latest()->first()` because I expect around 203 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is relationship query scopes like this

```php
$clients = App\Client::with(['bills' => function ($query) {
   $query->today();
}])->get();
```

Add `today()` scope to your `Bill` model like so
`Bill.php`

```php
public function scopeToday($query)
{
    // Change today by $activeSchoolYear if necessary
    return $query->whereDate('created_at', '<', today());
}
```

Assuming a `hasMany` relationship in the `Client`

```php
public function bills()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bill::class);
}
```

And data seeded like this
`DatabaseSeeder.php`

```php
// Will be returned because whereDoesntHave('bills')
$clientWithoutBills = Client::create([]);
$client = Client::create([]);
$client->bills()->createMany([
    [
        'name' => 'test',
        'created_at' => Carbon\Carbon::yesterday()
    ],
    [
        // Will not be returned because created today (not < today)
        'name' => 'test1'
    ],
    [
        // Will not be returned because created tomorrow
        'name' => 'test2',
        'created_at' => Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow()
    ]
]);
```

`Results`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-09-09 16:20:24",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-09 16:20:24",
        "bills": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "created_at": "2019-09-09 16:20:24",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-09 16:20:24",
        "bills": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test",
                "client_id": 2,
                "created_at": "2019-09-08 00:00:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-09-09 16:20:24"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. I tried to use your could with slight modifications, but I'm still getting some client's bills that aren't in defined range. I will try to play with your solution for a bit, will let you know if manage to get the desired result.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a sample of results you're expecting? it's hard to guess what you really want

Comment: Sorry I took this long to respond. I want to user where clause on only the last row inside the bills table. If that row fits the given condition, return it, else don't return anything. In my case, if I have 4 rows, and the first one doesn't fit the condition, it still returns that bill, because other 3 rows fit the given condition. I edited my question a bit

Comment: Update: Managed to do it, but I slightly changed the logic. I used `whereDoesntHave` function on query scope,  to watch for bills that are created after the given date. Will mark your answer as accepted, since it helped me solve this issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent whereDate().

```
->whereDate('created_at', '<', Carbon::parse($activeSchoolYear->start));
```

Comment: can you give the exact date string you are comparing to?